# Cannot opt in iOS Devices for Push Notifications

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios, push-notification

I have a Cordova app with the Marketing Cloud cordova plugin (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin).

The device is shown as "Not Opted In" and the "Opt Out Source" is marked as ServiceFeedback.

I have configured an APNS Prod Certificate for the app.

How can I send notification to iOS ? What is the cause of the Opt Out ?

Answer (score 3):

These issues are almost always a certificate issue (99.999% of the time).  See the troubleshooting push steps in the documentation for help.  (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/trouble/ios-debugging.html)

Also see the provisioning section of the docs.  (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-provision.html)

Comment: I tried both development and production APN Certs. In both scenarios, I see devices are not opted in. 
Is there any way to check whether marketing cloud is using Apple's Sandbox or Production to push notifications ?

Comment: Please open an investigation through your support representative.